# GCC (in any version) equivalent of clang's __type_pack_element to get Nth element of template parameter pack

Tags: c++, gcc, variadic-templates, intrinsics

https://reviews.llvm.org/D15421

clang has `__type_pack_element` which allows efficient indexing of parameter packs in variadic templates.  Is there a GCC equivalent?

I am not interested in using `tuple_element_t`.  I am looking for an alternative that is a compiler primitive

Comment: I don't see why you'd restrict yourself to a specific compiler like that. It seems to me much simpler (and understandable) to just use a cross-compiler solution with basic templates to me.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII I'm not sure about OP's rationale but I'm guessing that intrinsics may be implemented in O(1) while there are no guarantees about `tuple_element_t`...

Comment: Yes.  This is really about compilation speed

Comment: `__type_pack_element` has been available in GCC 14

Answer (score 7):

If you are really brave/crazy you could try and use the same techniques as kvasir::mpl does for this problem. In metaben.ch benchmarks its the same or faster than others who use __type_pack_element and works on GCC (note that the benchmark looks at every element, if you just ever index a few it will look quite different but usually if you want one then you eventually want the others too).

[benchmark](http://metaben.ch/type/clang++-4.0/at/index.html)

[implementation](https://github.com/kvasir-io/mpl/blob/development/src/kvasir/mpl/sequence/lookup.hpp)

[old blog post about it](http://odinthenerd.blogspot.de/2017/04/tree-based-lookup-why-kvasirmpl-is.html)